# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Regarding Cora Data

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

Hi I am getting an error for this line:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Feed", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!
```

The error I get says `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with only this info, but as a general info, you should never force (`!`) unwrapping optionals unless you're 100% sure the optional exists. In example of your MOC, you should do something like this.

```
if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Feed", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
}
else {
  NSLog("MOC is nil!")
}
```